How to change Retrofit's base url (that may or may not contain path segments) at runtime?
I know there are ways to change Retrofit's base url at runtime using Interceptors. For example: https://gist.github.com/swankjesse/8571a8207a5815cca1fb
But in the example above, the "base url" should consist only of the host itself. If the new base url contains path segments, it will not work.
My question is. How to change base urls to ones that may or may not contain one or more path segments? Example:

https://myapi.com/blog/v1
https://myapi.com/internal/blog/v1
...

Obs.: have in mind that the entire request url can contains more path segments. Example: {BASE_URL}/posts/recent

You can pass the URL as a parameter to your Retrofit API interface.
when you do so the base URL is ignored.
for example:
interface MyApi {
  @POST
  fun postUrl1(@Url url:String) : Call<ResponseBody>
}

